# How do I delete all white pixels from several layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, automation

I have a photoshop file with over a hundred layers. Each of these layers have white backgrounds. I need to remove all of these #FFFFFF pixels automatically. I'm not worried about the actual content being deleted or anything. None of the content contains any pure white pixels.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to remove the white layer by layer. There's no automated processes to strip white from all layers.

If it were me I'd probably use `Select > Color Range` to grab the white on each layer, then add a mask, repeat for each layer.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to accomplish with a simple action and simple script.

For an action I started recording a new action called `SelectWhite` and did `Select -> Color Range` (selected white) pressed `OK` then I hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the white, and then I pressed <kbd>CTRL + D</kbd> to de-select the current selection.

I then stopped recording my action.

Now you could just use this action manually on every layer or you could use a script to do it for you...

Then here's the code you need for the script:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
for(var i = 0; i < doc.layers.length; i++){
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[i];
    app.doAction("YOUR_ACTION_NAME_HERE", "YOUR_ACTION_SET_NAME_HERE");
    doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
}
```

This script will iterate through every layer and run the action you made on it.

On my computer the `app.doAction` line of code looked like this:

`app.doAction("SelectWhite", "Custom");`

Note that the first part `"SelectWhite"` is the name of your action and `"Custom"` is the action set the action is part of.

You can just open up Notepad and past this code in there, then save it as a `.jsx` file.

Now go to:

`File -> Scripts -> Browse...` and select your script and run it.

That's it!

**EDIT** If you don't want to do the work yourself, [I've extracted the action and script and placed them into a zip file.](https://mega.co.nz/#!SVIynJQa!MyumWwIohDCQgpUkN4ScBz7PX8EWP2iLy64MRBVhgpE) Just load the action into Photoshop and then run the script like I explained. You may need to adjust that one line of code in the script if there's some naming issues.

Comment: Oh man.  Thank god. A javascript for loop!! Maybe I can understand this software after all. Seriously Johannes. Thank you!  Is there a place I can read up on other script methods built into PS? (like doAction etc)

Comment: Absolutely. [See here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)

Answer (score 1):

make an ACTION from Scott's answer and apply it to all 100 layers.