# Apply script only to the 2nd layer of every PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, photoshop-scripting

How can I apply this code only to the 2nd layer of every PSD file? I also want to avoid color selection instead give the hex color code of black to remove.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
for(var i = 0; i < doc.layers.length; i++){
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[i];
    app.doAction("YOUR_ACTION_NAME_HERE", "YOUR_ACTION_SET_NAME_HERE");
    doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
}
```

The code appears here: [How do I delete all white pixels from several layers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21156)

Comment: That script is a loop for running an action on multiple layers in the same document, not single layers within multiple documents.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for apple.SE or SuperUser.SE

Comment: @Luciano but it's also on-topic here, or we wouldn't have the [tag:photoshop-scripting] tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Alt + F9 to open Action window
2. Click on "Create a set" button and rename it to mySet
   [image]
3. Click on "Create an Action" button and rename it to myAction
4. Go to Select -> Color Range (selected black) pressed OK then hit Delete
5. button on keyboard to delete the black colors, and then  press CTRL + D to deselect the current selection
6. Press Stop button in Action window
7. open notepad and copy and paste the following code

```
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[1];
    app.doAction("myAction", "mySet");
```

In notepad save the file with ".jsx" extention

go to Photoshop -> File -> Scripts -> Browse... and select your script and run it.
This script will run Action on your second layer